# Множественные фильтры JQ

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать множественный фильтр по таблице.

У меня имеется два инпута: текстовый и ранждовый.

По отдельности они работают. А как сделать чтобы учитывались оба фильтра?

```js
// живой поиск по таблице
  function updateTable(value) {
    $('.table tbody tr').filter(function () {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
  }

  // получает value по отжатию клавиши и обновляет таблицу
  search.keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    updateTable(value);
  });

  // получает value по отжатию мыши и обновляет таблицу
  range.mouseup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    updateTable(value);
  });
```

Comment: В качестве значения у вас используется `$(this).val()` но в разных функциях значения берётся из своего инпута. Очевидно, надо в каждой функции получать как собственное значение, так и соседа.

И главное - не вставляйте примеры кода в виде скриншота. Потрудитесь вставить код как кусок кода (снипет).

Comment: Вставил код. Надо что-то вроде `data.filter(option1).filter(option2)` сделать, а я никак не переделаю текущий код под это.

Comment: Сюда бы добавить минимальный HTML с воспроизводимой ошибкой. Так, на глаз - вроде бы должно работать...

Comment: фильтры работают, только работают они по раздельности. Мне же необходимо, чтобы они работали вместе. Т.е если я отсортировал код через input-text, а потом  через range (тут выбираю год), то нужно чтобы уже отсортированный код сортировался и наоборот

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: Вместо одного значения проверяйте оба и объедините условия

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите на отсортированных строках применить другой фильтр, то можно использовать селектор `:visible` в jquery.

```
$('.table tbody tr:visible')
```

Либо не передавать value в функцию, а собирать их уж в самой функции с обоих инпутов, и там применять в фильтре через &&